# Problem with iPad personal hotspot on OS X 10.11

Tags: ipad, tethering, macos

I'm having problems with iPad tethered USB internet share (personal hotspot).
OS X 10.11. (15A226f) and iOS 9b (13A4325c)

Tethering via USB to iPads internet has worked before, but as far as I remember it stopped working after updating OS X to 10.11., so most likely the problem is NOT iOS 9, but the OS X 10.11

I'v already tried rebooting both devices, reconnecting everything etc., but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

As this is an issue involving Beta Software, it should be reported to Apple via the [Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com).  Sign in with your Apple ID or developer account.

As to why: Check again your OS X Network settings.

Is there a fix: Perhaps with the next Beta release.